# Generating all combinations of a String with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, combinations

I need to generate all possible combinations of a string, using multithreading to split the work equally among N threads. So the string `cat` would output:

```
c, a, t, ca, ct, ac, at, ta, tc, cat, cta, tac, tca, act, atc
```

Each thread contains a `startIndex` and `endIndex` and does a different processing of the string. Right now I can generate all permutations of a string but I am absolutely stumped on what I need to do to modify it to get all combinations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have right now:

```
public void run() {
    for(int i = startIndex; (i < endIndex); i++) {
        swap(word, 0, i); // Swap character to zero location.
        permuteAndCheck(word, 1); // Recursively check permutations
        swap(word, 0, i); // Undo swap
    }
}

private void permuteAndCheck(char[] word, int start) {
    if (start < word.length) {
        // Not yet at the deepest recursion level to compare permutations.
        for(int i = start; (i < word.length); i++) {
            swap(word, start, i);
            permuteAndCheck(word, start + 1);
            swap(word, start, i); // Restore entry back from previous swap
        }
        return;
    }

    System.out.print(word + ", ");
}

private static final void swap(char[] word, int index1, int index2) {
    char temp  = word[index1];
    word[index1] = word[index2];
    word[index2] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget tca, atc and cta.

Comment: .. unless order doesn't matter, in which case you should forget those. <grin/> But since ac and ca were both listed...

Comment: I didn't list 3 of them. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, OP meant "permutations", not "combinations".

Comment: I meant combinations (subsets)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all the combinations (i.e. power set of the characters), then you already know there are 2^k possibilities, k being the number of characters.

The first thread then handles the 1st to the (2^k)/N th combination, the second thread handles the 1+ (2^k)/N th to  2*(2^k)/N th combination, etc.

To obtain the j-th string, you look at the binary representation of j, and grab the characters where the corresponding digit is a '1'. i.e. the 5th(binary:101) combination of "cat" is c_t.